# Start another activity to show image correspondingly of json after clicking the items in recycler view

Tags: android, json

I have a recycler view which shows a list of all the movies title after parsing json . Now what i would like to achieve is that i want to start another activity to show a poster of each movie title . Like when i click on first list item named "Jurassic" then it should show me the jurassic poster,
second item named "The planet" , it should show me the poster of the planet movie after clicking on it.

Here it's my code for the onClickListener in my adapter

NowPlayingAdapter.class

```
 package swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.helper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;

import java.util.List;

import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.Fragments.ContentFragment;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.Fragments.Top;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.MainActivity;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.R;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.activity.Single;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.app.AppController;

/**
 * Created by Shiva on 01-07-2015.
 */
public class NowPlayingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NowPlayingAdapter.NowPlayingHolder> {
    @Override
    public NowPlayingHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listnow , parent ,false);


        return new NowPlayingHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NowPlayingHolder holder, int position) {
        NowPlayingInfo trailer_info = trailer.get(position);

         holder.title.setText(trailer_info.getTitle());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trailer.size();
    }

    Activity activity;
    public List<NowPlayingInfo> trailer ;
    public NowPlayingAdapters(Activity activity , List<NowPlayingInfo> trailer){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.trailer = trailer;
    }




    public static class NowPlayingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        protected TextView title ;

        public NowPlayingHolder(View v){

            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleText);





        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            List<NowPlayingInfo> list;

            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext() , Single.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Single.class` is :

```
package swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.R;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.app.AppController;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.helper.NowPlayingAdapter;
import swipe.vivek.com.swipedown.helper.NowPlayingInfo;

/**
 * Created by Shiva on 02-07-2015.
 */
public class Single extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = Single.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://private-8149-themoviedb.apiary-mock.com/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<NowPlayingInfo> bottom = new ArrayList<NowPlayingInfo>() ;

    NowPlayingAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.singleimage);
        adapter = new NowPlayingAdapter(this, bottom);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                NowPlayingInfo trailer = new NowPlayingInfo();


                                String iss = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + jsonObject.getString("poster_path") ;
                                trailer.setImage(iss);
                                bottom.add(trailer);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Its not displaying the poster ..just the empty image view. pls help me.

Comment: You're logging the response. What does it say?

Comment: What do you mean by logging?

Comment: Your adapter is an orphan. There is no UI for the adapter.

Comment: Adapter is fine. It works. Please read my comments below what exactly I want sir.

Comment: If Single should show a single image why does it need an adapter?

Comment: logging means to call one of the Log methods to print something to the console/logcat.

Comment: Oh log shows:. it makes an request to the URL and shows the whole json. And then nothing . Did you see the single class? At the last am adding data to list..like bottom.add(trailer) ..but we have only image which does not require a list. How do I make it right? I think there is the problem

Comment: Could you add the code of the other Activity?

Comment: Which one sir? And this is what I want to do:

Comment: pass the images position to the new activity with an intent on the click that starts the new activity.

Use that position to display your image.﻿                                                      (I don't know how do I get position)

Comment: ViewHolder has a method named 'getAdaperPosition()' that you can use to get the position in adapter.

Comment: I fixed it already :) its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<NowPlayingInfo> list;

        Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext() , Single.class);
        view.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

You're not doing anything with list there in your onClick method. My guess is the Single class doesn't know what to display. Try logging out iss to make sure that URL goes to an actual image.

Comment: Sorry yeah. I was trying something there. I forgot to edit the list.

Comment: Problem I know .. Because its not an issue with the JsonRequest. I have tested both the image and the title.. They were showing.

Comment: Now I have separated them. Title should be shown in a list view. And image in another activity with the single imageview of the corresponding title. (After clicking the title)